# Connection to Yahoo Finance with requests.get() not working anymore

Tags: python, python-requests, yahoo-finance

until recently I was able to connect to Yahoo Finance, which allowed me to fill my stock screener with json-data. However, since a couple of weeks, I am not able to connect to Yahoo Finance anymore. Apparently, Yahoo Finance blocked the *traditional* way of accessing its data and I am wondering if there is a work around to reestablish such a connection.

Here are a few technical details how I was connecting to Yahoo Finance (which worked without any problems during the last 2 years):

```
r = requests.get(url_root_yahoo + ticker + key_stats_yahoo + ticker)
data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
quote_store = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']
statistics = quote_store['defaultKeyStatistics']
profit_margin = statistics['profitMargins']['raw']
```

But now I am getting the following error message:

```
File "stock_screener_4.py", line 80, in <module>
quote_store = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']
NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

Any hints how to reestablish the connection?

Thanks a lot.

P.S. Minimum working example:

```
import os
import urllib.request
import requests, re, json

p = re.compile(r'root\.App\.main = (.*);')

url_root_yahoo = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'
key_stats_yahoo = '/key-statistics?p='
ticker = 'AAPL'
execute_next_block = 1

r = requests.get(url_root_yahoo + ticker + key_stats_yahoo + ticker)

try:
    data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
except (KeyError, IndexError, TypeError):
    execute_next_block = 0

try:
    quote_store = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']
    statistics = quote_store['defaultKeyStatistics']
except (KeyError, IndexError, TypeError):
     execute_next_block = 0
```

Comment: This code cannot produce that error.  `data` clearly is defined on line 2, so there's no way that error could happen.

Comment: did you check line 80 in your script? Do you have `data = ... before line 80`? Maybe you use `data = ...` in `if/else` or in `try/except` and it is skiped - so it is not created. Better show minimal working code which gives this error because your corrent example can't gives this problem. So your real probem can be totally different then connection.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks for your answer. In my question, I merely posted parts of the code, which does not give a complete picture. I will provide a better example below...

Comment: @snakecharmerb That is a pure conjecture of myself since the script, which I have been using for almost 2 years, suddenly stopped working. I thought using the wording "apparently" would make this clear.

Comment: @furas You are right. I am indeed using `data=...` in `try/except` and the data object is not created. I added a minimum working example to my original question above. Thanks...

Comment: I tried to run your code. I got the same error, when I checked the content of r.text, I can see the following content. is the url correct? `<p id="message-1">Thank you for your patience.</p>\n      <p id="message-2">Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue.`

Comment: server needs correct header `User-Agent` (probably to generate different HTML for different devices: desktop, notebook, tablet, phone) - `requests.get(..., headers={'USER-AGENT': "Mozilla/5.0"})` - and this gives me some JSON `data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']` but it doesn't have `['QuoteSummaryStore']` - probably they changed something more in data structure.

Comment: @r-beginners The URL is correct. You can check that by pasting the URL https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=AAPL from the above example into your browser.

Comment: @furas Thanks a lot. Simply pasting `headers={'USER-AGENT': "Mozilla/5.0"}`into `requests.get()`solved the issue and all my stock screeners are running again. You made my Sunday!